# What's the best way to attach timber cleats to stair stringers?

Tags: stairs, fastener

I'm using 2x4 timber cleats to support the treads for a set of stairs going up to a deck. The stringers are 2x10 and both the stringers and 2x4 are pressure treated pine. What would be the best size and type of fastener to use? I was planning on using M10 carriage/coach bolts.

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to figure that out from the load table mumbo jumbo.

TABLE 9.14 LAG SCREW (BOLT) CAPACITY FOR SINGLE SHEAR CONNECTIONS (LBS.), page 69, [Chicago deck code, PDF](https://www.chicago.gov/content/dam/city/depts/bldgs/general/Porch/Porch2011/RevPorch_Guide52611_Secured.pdf).

3/8ths (M10) is the middle of the road; it's better than using 1/4" or 5/16". Use stainless steel fasteners. You *must* pre drill your holes for cleats. Ideally it's an actually cut stringer; notice how cleats aren't even an option.

Comment: Seems like I have 2 options: coach bolts or structural screws. I would think that coach bolts would be the better option.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://www.decksgo.com/attaching-stair-treads.html) states the usual method is to use four #8 x 3" screws - I am going from memory but I believe that's what I have used in the past.  That's quite a bit smaller than what you're planning.

More recently, I have used the angle brackets made by Simpson Strong Tie and others which are made for the purpose.

[image: Simpson Strong-Tie TA]

I prefer the way these look and there won't be a question on inspection.  The cost isn't a big deal if it is just a few steps.  If there are a lot of steps it adds up.  There is no doubt the cleats are strong, as long as the wood remains solid.

Comment: Yes, the brackets would be better but they're not available where I am. A #8 screw is only .164". That seems a bit on the small side to me.